# Data labels in Highcharts Activity Gauge

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am looking for a way to add Data Labels in the [Activity Gauge](https://www.highcharts.com/demo/gauge-activity) chart of Highcharts. I want data labels to spoke out from the arc just like it happens in a regular [pie chart](https://www.highcharts.com/demo/pie-basic).

I figure out a way to do this by placing a transparent pie chart behind the activity gauge and then I take out data labels from the pie chart and add it to the activity gauge and then remove the pie chart altogether. This works fine but has limitations and less scalable.

I was wondering if it can be achieved by using some other intelligent techniques?

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {

  chart: {
    type: 'solidgauge',
    height: '110%',
  },

  title: {
    text: 'Activity',
    style: {
      fontSize: '24px'
    }
  },

  tooltip: {
    enabled: false
  },

  pane: {
    startAngle: 0,
    endAngle: 360,
    background: [{ // Track for Move
      outerRadius: '112%',
      innerRadius: '88%',
      backgroundColor: Highcharts.color(Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0])
        .setOpacity(0.3)
        .get(),
      borderWidth: 0
    }, { // Track for Exercise
      outerRadius: '87%',
      innerRadius: '63%',
      backgroundColor: Highcharts.color(Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1])
        .setOpacity(0.3)
        .get(),
      borderWidth: 0
    }, { // Track for Stand
      outerRadius: '62%',
      innerRadius: '38%',
      backgroundColor: Highcharts.color(Highcharts.getOptions().colors[2])
        .setOpacity(0.3)
        .get(),
      borderWidth: 0
    }]
  },

  yAxis: {
    min: 0,
    max: 100,
    lineWidth: 0,
    tickPositions: []
  },

  plotOptions: {
    solidgauge: {
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: false
      },
      linecap: 'round',
      stickyTracking: false,
      rounded: true
    }
  },

  series: [{
    name: 'Move',
    data: [{
      color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0],
      radius: '112%',
      innerRadius: '88%',
      y: 80
    }]
  }, {
    name: 'Exercise',
    data: [{
      color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1],
      radius: '87%',
      innerRadius: '63%',
      y: 65
    }]
  }, {
    name: 'Stand',
    data: [{
      color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[2],
      radius: '62%',
      innerRadius: '38%',
      y: 50
    }]
  }]
});
```

```css
#container {
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/solid-gauge.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/accessibility.js"></script>

<figure class="highcharts-figure">
  <div id="container"></div>
</figure>
```

Answer (score 0):

I like your idea with the dummy pie chart behind the main one. You can consider using `alignTo` feature to improve it - https://www.highcharts.com/docs/advanced-chart-features/pie-datalabels-alignment

Another solution that came to my mind is by positioning the `solidGauge dataLabels` and render custom paths for each. Check this basic demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/j4of9nLz/

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.render

API: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer#path

Comment: Positioning the solid gauge labels is a more robust approach. Pie data labels does not work because the max values and the angles are configurable in my activity gauge so it really gets hard to calculate the pies positions.

Can you think of some approach in which we are drawing these labels from the centre of the arcs of activity gauge rather than start, and to keep them left and right?